# How detect whether the request made is valid?

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

I am connecting 10 servlets in java to each other. In this case when I load the first servlet it must end up at the last servlet showing the output as 10... And I was able to do that...
But the problem is that when I used the following code to pass data from one servlet to the other when I start not from the first servlet there is no output..

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        int pass=1;
       if(request.isRequestedSessionIdFromURL()==true)
       {
             pass=Integer.parseInt(request.getAttribute("passInt").toString());
             pass++;
        } 

        request.setAttribute("passInt",pass);



        RequestDispatcher dis =  request.getRequestDispatcher("/C");
        dis.forward(request, response);  

    } finally {            
        out.close();
    }
}
```

And in this I want to get the value as 9 when I load the 2nd servlet. But it is not happening...can anyone help me to get the correct method to filter whether if there is a passed attribute from the linked servlet so that I can avoid this error?